# How to add video in parallax Slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, yii2

I have a parrallax slider, I have put  just image and  description on slider, and I want to add a video, this is my code:

```
{ <div id="da-slider" class="da-slider">
    <div class="da-slide">
        <h2>Vidéo PUB</h2> 
        <p>loading</p> <!--wanna put the video here -->
    </div>
    <div class="da-slide">
        <h2>Affréteurs</h2>
        <p></p>
        <div class="da-img"><img src="" alt="" /></div>
   </div> }
```

My problem is the video is static.

I'm currently using this slider:

- [Yii2 Da-Slider](https://github.com/mickgeek/yii2-daslider)

I want to:

1. Add it to the first slide
2. Set it so it autoplays
3. After the video finishes playing I want the slider to automatically resume and move to the next slide.

How can I do this?

Comment: so you want an html video tag?

Comment: Is this all your code?

Comment: my problem is the video is static , I wanna get it just in the first slide , after watching it , I wanna move to the sacond slide automatically so how  style it ???

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting up a YouTube account to host your video on.

If the site is popular then it offloads the strain of serving the video file over to YouTube's fast, dedicated servers.

Once you have got your YouTube video uploaded you can add it to the slide by clicking the Share button beneath the video and then clicking Embed. This will give you a snippet of code like this which you can use in your slider code above:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_dJCLaoBZvM?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Notice the `rel=0` on the end. That stops it suggesting other videos once yours has finished playing which makes the whole thing more professional. You can also add `autoplay=1` if you want it to start playing straight away. There are also more advanced integrations that you can do where you control the chrome of the video player (the skin around the edge).

Comment: my problem is the video is static , I wanna get it just in the first slide , after watching it , I wanna move to the sacond slide automatically so how to style it ???

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before with parallax and it comes out looking amazing.

I prefer this method to a service like Youtube or Vimeo because you have more control and be able to style it how you want more effectively.

You want to get your video in mp4 and ogg format.  You can do this with VLC media player.  It's free.

Then I used the html5 `<video>` tag ([Link Here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)). here is a sample.  You will want to style for position, etc... in your CSS.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: my problem is the video is static , I wanna get it just in the first slide  , after watching it , I wanna move to the sacond  slide automatically so how to style it ???